# IMAP: How to determine maximum allowed folder name and path length?

Tags: imap

I'm developing a specialized IMAP client that uses an email server to store messages in automatically generated folders organized in a hierarchy. Currently I'm using Dovecot as email server and sometimes run into its limits. As [per the documentation](https://doc.dovecot.org/admin_manual/namespaces/#folder-name-lengths) there is a 255 byte limit for folder names and another limit for the whole folder path that depends on the used storage mechanism (254 vs. 4096 bytes). Other OSes or email servers might have different limits.

How do I query the email server about those limits so I can adhere to them? Does the IMAP protocol support such a query? Or some IMAP protocol extension? Or do I have to "probe" the server's limits by creating a dummy folder hierarchy until it fails?

Comment: There’s no way to query this information.  Since it was expected that only humans would make short human readable names, there was no real reason to specify it.  Keeping it below ~250 chars is probably a pretty good rule of thumb though.